# Can you store encrypted passwords in ConnectWise Manage or will they always be plain text?

Tags: encryption, passwords, database, password-management, database-administration

Title pretty much says it all. I need to store passwords for devices and configurations but I want them to be stored securely and encrypted. Can this be done with ConnectWise Manage?

Comment: ConnectWise has 6 different products.  Which product are we talking about?

Comment: Sorry. Connectwise Manage